# calling a function on button click in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I have multiple buttons on an HTML page. When a user clicks them, I want to call respective functions and manipulate the database.

I don't know if Django-forms are the right thing to use here. If yes, should I use different forms for different buttons?

Answer (score 3):

Just map your `view` **function** to a `url` and call it, for example:

**views.py**

```
def remove_item(request, pk):
    item = Item.objects.get(pk=pk)
    item.delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('remove_item/<int:pk>/', views.remove_item, name='remove_item'),
]
```

**item.html**

```
{{ item.name }}
<a href='{% url 'remove_item' item.pk %}'><button>Delete</button></a>
```

This is just an example **function** to delete an `item` that *supposedly* exists.

To answer your other question: Yes you can use forms with `action` attribute containing a `url` to the **view** that would handle its submittion (that usually means that form processes some sent data) and yes you can use multiple **forms**/**buttons** on the same page.

Comment: But I don't want to create separate URLs for every button.

Comment: Well you'll have to my friend, welcome to web-development :)

Comment: Are there any other methods? Like how facebook's like button work without redirecting to another URL?

Comment: Facebook is using React.js to display their API data on webpages, when you click the `Like` button the `Post` or a `Picture` it activates the endpoint in the API, component gets updated asynchronously and after that the data is being sent to the database, if you want to understand it better then you have to read up on React components and states but for now I recommend starting with Django documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial01/